# Gmail not recognising email markup

Tags: html, gmail, google-schemas

I tried to test RSVP Action of email markup. I added the content of the mail with markup and sent to self mail (DKIM and SPF are not needed). 
But the email markup is not recognised.

The markup is:

```
<p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: <span itemprop="reservationNumber">IO12345</span><br/>
      Order for: <span itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">John Smith</span>
      </span><br/>
      <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
        Event: <span itemprop="name">Google I/O 2017</span><br/>
        <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2017-05-15T08:30:00-08:00">Start time: May 15th 2017 8:00am PST</time><br/>
        Venue: <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
          <span itemprop="name">Moscone Center</span>
          <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">800 Howard St.</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">San Francisco</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>,
            <span itemprop="postalCode">94103</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressCountry">US</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </p>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does "the email markup is not recognised" mean? Is it rendered as text? Is it stripped out entirely resulting in everything turning up on one line?  Are some particular elements not having the effect you expect? Something else?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).